How to fix it? Excel VBA - Run-time error 438 Object doesn't Support
Sub GenerateNumberCombinations()
    Dim numbers As Variant
    Dim combinations As Collection
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim row As Long

    numbers = Array(1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 9)

       Set combinations = New Collection

    For i = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
        For j = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
            For k = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
                combinations.Add numbers(i) & numbers(j) & numbers(k)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

  ''' This is Debug''''
    combinations.Sort 

   ''''''''
    row = 2
    For Each combination In combinations
        Cells(row, 1).Value = combination
        row = row + 1
    Next combination
End Sub

Debug 438

A Collection doesn’t have a Sort method

Black cat already has explained why you are getting the error.
To sort a colleciton you can use bubble sort. Here is an example.
Option Explicit

Dim vItm As Variant

Sub Sample()
    Dim cFruit As Collection
    
    Set cFruit = New Collection

    '~~> Sample collection
    cFruit.Add "Mango", "Mango"
    cFruit.Add "Apple", "Apple"
    cFruit.Add "Peach", "Peach"
    cFruit.Add "Kiwi", "Kiwi"
    cFruit.Add "Lime", "Lime"
    
    '~~> Output before sorting
    For Each vItm In cFruit
        Debug.Print vItm
    Next vItm
    
    Debug.Print "-----------------------------"
    
    '~~> Sorting the collection
    SortCollection cFruit

    '~~> Output after sorting
    For Each vItm In cFruit
        Debug.Print vItm
    Next vItm
End Sub

'~~> Proc to sort a collection
Private Sub SortCollection(c As Collection)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vTemp As Variant
    
    '~~> Bubble Sort
    For i = 1 To c.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To c.Count
            If c(i) > c(j) Then
                '~~> Store the lesser item
                vTemp = c(j)
                '~~> Remove the lesser item
                c.Remove j
                '~~> Re-add the lesser item before the greater Item
                c.Add vTemp, vTemp, i
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Output


Sort can not be applied on a collection. But on a Range it can.
To apply a sort on a Range object move and change the sort command line
Sub GenerateNumberCombinations()


Dim numbers As Variant
Dim combinations As Collection
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim row As Long

numbers = Array(1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 9)

   Set combinations = New Collection

For i = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
    For j = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
        For k = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
            combinations.Add numbers(i) & numbers(j) & numbers(k)
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

''''''''
row = 2
For Each combination In combinations
Cells(row, 1).Value = combination
row = row + 1
Next combination

Columns("A").Sort Columns("A")    'added to sort the generated range
'or
'Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row).Sort Columns("A")
' if you want to keep the original position of the range.

End Sub



Generate Concatenated Combinations

As a workaround, you could sort the given array and only then generate the numbers.
Since it's a small array, any algorithm will do. The QuickSort algorithm is supposed to be one of the fastest.
Since you can determine the number of resulting elements, using a 2D array instead of a collection is preferable. Then you can write the resulting values to the worksheet in one go which is more efficient  (faster) than writing each element to a cell.
If you declare the array as String, all digits (leading zeros) will show for every combination and you won't have to format the range to do so.

Main
Sub GenerateConcatenatedCombinations()
    
    Const ITEMS_COUNT As Long = 3
    
    Dim Numbers() As Variant: Numbers = Array(1, 4, 7, 0, 3, 9)
    
    Dim LB As Long: LB = LBound(Numbers)
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(Numbers)
    
    QSort Numbers, LB, UB
    
    Dim Count As Long: Count = (UB - LB + 1) ^ ITEMS_COUNT
    Dim Data() As String: ReDim Data(1 To Count, 1 To 1)
       
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, Row As Long
       
    For i = LB To UB
        For j = LB To UB
            For k = LB To UB
                Row = Row + 1
                Data(Row, 1) = Numbers(i) & Numbers(j) & Numbers(k)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    With ws.Range("A2")
        .Resize(Count).Value = Data
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row - Count + 1).Offset(Count).Clear
    End With

End Sub

Help
Sub QSort( _
        ByRef Arr As Variant, _
        ByVal LB As Long, _
        ByVal UB As Long)
    Dim Piv As Variant, Tmp As Variant, LO As Long, HI As Long
    LO = LB: HI = UB: Piv = Arr((LB + UB) \ 2)
    Do While LO <= HI
        Do While Arr(LO) < Piv: LO = LO + 1: Loop
        Do While Arr(HI) > Piv: HI = HI - 1: Loop
        If LO <= HI Then
            Tmp = Arr(LO)
            Arr(LO) = Arr(HI): Arr(HI) = Tmp: LO = LO + 1: HI = HI - 1
        End If
    Loop
    If LB < HI Then QSort Arr, LB, HI
    If LO < UB Then QSort Arr, LO, UB
End Sub

